# Show GPX traces in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gps

Do you know if there is a map app that allows to show GPX traces?

I have downloaded the GPX file of a hiking route and I would like to follow it on the OSMscout map or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have tried **Bike maps** although it is very limited? I am still awaiting for someone to make foxtrotGPS work on touch devices; so far not impressed with Osmscout or uNav.

Comment: I tried all the gps related apps but in the end I gave up and installed android. Of course not just for that but also. I found the ubuntu phone too limited to be used as main (only) phone

Comment: I tend to agree - Ubuntu touch has still got a long way to go to compete with the commercial alternatives. It is still pretty much a beta at best. I am going to persevere as I really want it to work.